# Create transaction with inputs of two different HD wallets

Tags: multi-signature, bip174-psbt

Is it possible to create one Bitcoin transaction with input UTXOs of two different HD-Wallets? E.g. using an UTXO of a Software Wallet and one UTXO of an Hardware Wallet.

Of course I think it is possible. The question is more what it is the best workflow/software to do this.

Regards steff

Comment: Related: [Partially Signed Bitcoin Transaction (PSBT)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103195/13866)

Comment: Here is a detailed walkthrough of how to do this with Bitcoin Core: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57253/how-do-i-spend-bitcoins-from-multiple-wallets-in-a-single-transaction/89169#89169